# Can not deserialize property type array, saved from other application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, nhibernate

I have two applications, website, and Console application.

Website saves the record and console application get the record to do notifications.

In the website, the record is saved with success, but console application can not deserialize property PerfisDeAcesso.

Both applications have the class below

//Domain class

```
public class Comunicado : Entity<int>
{
   public virtual string Titulo { get; set; }
   public virtual string Mensagem { get; set; }
   public virtual PerfilDeAcesso[] PerfisDeAcesso { get; set; }
}
```

//NHibernate mapping

```
public class ComunicadoMap : ClassMap<Comunicado>
{
    public ComunicadoMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Titulo).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Mensagem).Not.Nullable().Length(4001);
        Map(x => x.PerfisDeAcesso);
    }
}
```

In MySQL table, the column type is BLOB

[image: In my database, the type is blob]

In the console application, occurs the error, but the console application
doesn't have the namespace Condomundo.Domain.Core, this namespace belongs to the Web application

[image: Error message]

Comment: You need to read column type BLOB as `byte[]` then convert it to Bitmap which can be used to set the Image Property

Comment: I change the property type to byte[] and it works, thanks very much, you help me.

Comment: Welcome, So I will post it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read column type `BLOB` as `byte[]` then convert it to `Bitmap` which can be used to set the Image Property.

> BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have
>   the binary character set and collation, and comparison and sorting are
>   based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.

[Reading a BLOB from the Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-blob-reading.html)